# Impedir mutiplos clicks no submit!

Tags: jquery, html

tenho um formulário que cadastra o nome da pessoa em um banco de dados via ajax, porém as vezes demora ao enviar e retorna e dou mas 2 ou 3 clicks ele envia o mesmo dado! queria saber como impedir isso, já tentei:

```
    <script>
    var statSend = false;
    function checkSubmit() {
    if (!statSend) {
    statSend = true;
    return true;
    } else {
    alert("O formulário esta sendo enviado…");
    return false; }
    }
    </script>
```

e

```
    onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value = 'Aguarde…'; this.form.submit();"
```

e dentre outros, mas nenhum deles funcionaram! alguém ajuda!?

```
             <h4>Cadastro de Nome</h4>
    <form id="cadUsuario" method="post">
        <label>Nome:</label><input required type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Salvar" id="salvar"  />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {    
            $("#cadUsuario").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var FormData = $(this).serialize(); 
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST", 
                  url: "salvar.php",
                  dataType: "json", // Add datatype
                  data: FormData
                }).done(function (data) {
                    $('#cadUsuario').trigger("reset");
                    var mensagem = '';
                    if (!data.insert){
                        mensagem = 'Falha no cadastro';
                    }
                /* if(!data.email){
                    mensagem += 'Falha no envio do email';
                   }*/
                    if(data.insert/* && data.email*/){
                        mensagem = 'Operação realizda com sucesso';
                    }
                    alert(mensagem);
                }, "json");
            return false;
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926816/how-to-prevent-form-from-submitting-multiple-times-from-client-side

Comment: Verificar no php, se esse registro já existe antes de inseri-lo, não poderia ser?

Comment: é na verdade pode haver dois nomes iguais cadastrados, mas não podem tem cadastrados por acidente sabe, disparado sem querer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você criar uma variável e dentro de `.submit(...);` setar o valor `true` e com o evento [`jqXHR.ajax.always`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) setar false novamente, no começo do `.submit` adicione uma `if` para checar se já está como `true`.

Antes de qualquer coisa, **remova** isto:

```
onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value = 'Aguarde…'; this.form.submit();"
```

E esta função também é **dispensável**:

```
var statSend = false;
function checkSubmit() {
if (!statSend) {
statSend = true;
return true;
} else {
alert("O formulário esta sendo enviado…");
return false; }
}
```

O resultado deve ser:

```
$(function () {
    var enviandoForm = false;

    $("#cadUsuario").submit(function (e) {
        if (enviandoForm) {
              return false;
        }

        /*
        Isto é apenas para desabilitar o form, mas a garantia
        está na variavel booleana
        */
        this.disabled = true;

        enviandoForm = true;

        e.preventDefault();
        var FormData = $(this).serialize(); 

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: "salvar.php",
          dataType: "json", // Add datatype
          data: FormData
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#cadUsuario').trigger("reset");
            var mensagem = '';
            if (!data.insert){
                mensagem = 'Falha no cadastro';
            }
        /* if(!data.email){
            mensagem += 'Falha no envio do email';
           }*/
            if(data.insert/* && data.email*/){
                mensagem = 'Operação realizda com sucesso';
            }
            alert(mensagem);
        }).always(function() {
            enviandoForm = false; //Libera o form
            this.disabled = false;
        });

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Perfeitooooo! tentei usando a troca da class e funcionou também, mas acredito que usando o próprio jquery pra isso fica mais enxuto! obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
 <h4>Cadastro de Nome</h4>
<form id="cadUsuario" method="post">
    <label>Nome:</label><input required type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" id="salvar"  />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {    
        $("#cadUsuario").submit(function (e) {
        $('#salvar').prop('disabled', true);
        e.preventDefault();
        var FormData = $(this).serialize(); 
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST", 
              url: "salvar.php",
              dataType: "json", // Add datatype
              data: FormData
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#cadUsuario').trigger("reset");
                var mensagem = '';
                if (!data.insert){
                    mensagem = 'Falha no cadastro';
                }
            /* if(!data.email){
                mensagem += 'Falha no envio do email';
               }*/
                if(data.insert/* && data.email*/){
                    mensagem = 'Operação realizda com sucesso';
                }
                alert(mensagem);
                $('#salvar').prop('disabled', false);
            }, "json");
        return false;
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Desabilitando o botão de fato durante o `ajax`, e liberando novamente somente após o `alert`, garantindo assim que não haja duplicidade de dados indevidamente.

Comment: Uma dica, troque `$('input[type="submit"]')` por `$('input[type="submit"]', $this)` e no começo do submit crie uma variavel assim `.submit(function(e) { var $this = this;`, assim não vai afetar outros formulários na página.

Comment: Não sabia que isso era possível, de qualquer forma depois que observei também que o `input` dele tem um id e estava prestes a editar...rsrs vlw pela informação! @GuilhermeNascimento